# Whats is a good algorithm for cat movement in the game "Trap the cat"

Tags: javascript

in order for the game to work, I had to do the movement of the cat, however, I had difficulties with this - the cat changes its trajectory of movement with a delay in the turn.

i have been tried this code

```
var p = 61;
```

```
var cords = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);var cordp = new Array(1)cordp[0] = cords;
```

```
function PT(element, cords) {
```

```
element.setAttribute("onclick", "0")
element.style.backgroundColor = "darkgreen"
element.setAttribute("value", "false")
```

```
// cords
var img = document.getElementById("img1");
if (cords == 1) {
    p -= 1;
    var td = document.getElementById("td" + p);
    var check = td.getAttribute("value");
    if (check == "true") {
        td.appendChild(img);
    }
    else {
        p += 1;
        cords[0] = cords[0] + 1;
        console.log(cords);
    }
    if (check == "lose") {
        td.appendChild(img);
        openModal();
    }
}

else if (cords == 2) {
    p -= 12;
    var td = document.getElementById("td" + p);
    var check = td.getAttribute("value");
    if (check == "true") {
        td.appendChild(img);
    }
    else {
        p += 12;
        cords[0] = cords[0] + 1;
        console.log(cords);
    }
    if (check == "lose") {
        td.appendChild(img);
        openModal();
    }
}
else if (cords == 3) {
    p -= 11;
    var td = document.getElementById("td" + p);
    var check = td.getAttribute("value");
    if (check == "true") {
        td.appendChild(img);
    }
    else {
        p += 11;
        cords[0] = cords[0] + 1;
        console.log(cords);
    }
    if (check == "lose") {
        td.appendChild(img);
        openModal();
    }
}

else if (cords == 4) {
    p -= 10;
    var td = document.getElementById("td" + p);
    var check = td.getAttribute("value");
    if (check == "true") {
        td.appendChild(img);
    }
    else {
        p += 10;
        cords[0] = cords[0] + 1;
        console.log(cords);
    }
    if (check == "lose") {
        td.appendChild(img);
        openModal();
    }
}
else if (cords == 5) {
    p += 1;
    var td = document.getElementById("td" + p);
    var check = td.getAttribute("value");
    if (check == "true") {
        td.appendChild(img);
    }
    else {
        p -= 1;
        cords[0] = cords[0] + 1;
        console.log(cords);
    }
    if (check == "lose") {
        td.appendChild(img);
        openModal();
    }
}
else if (cords == 6) {
    p += 12;
    var td = document.getElementById("td" + p);
    var check = td.getAttribute("value");
    if (check == "true") {
        td.appendChild(img);
    }
    else {
        p -= 12;
        cords[0] = cords[0] + 1;
        console.log(cords);
    }
    if (check == "lose") {
        td.appendChild(img);
        openModal();
    }
}
else if (cords == 7) {
    p += 11;
    var td = document.getElementById("td" + p);
    var check = td.getAttribute("value");
    if (check == "true") {
        td.appendChild(img);
    }
    else {
        p -= 11;
        cords[0] = cords[0] + 1;
        console.log(cords);
    }
    if (check == "lose") {
        td.appendChild(img);
        openModal();
    }
}
else if (cords == 8) {
    p += 10;
    var td = document.getElementById("td" + p);
    var check = td.getAttribute("value");
    if (check == "true") {
        td.appendChild(img);
    }
    else {
        p -= 10;
        cords[0] = cords[0] - 7;
        console.log(cords);
    }
    if (check == "lose") {
        td.appendChild(img);
        openModal();
    }
}
```

p - the cat place

cords- at the beginning of each round, the direction in which the cat will go is generated
element

element- the cell that the player clicked on(the game is made through the table and cells)